# encryption key protection in C#

Tags: c#, encryption

Is there an industry standard for solving following problem:

Story; I have a program (=>game) that saves it state (=>level,..) in an xml file; this state should not be user editable; and I want to prevent people writing patch software that can patch my xml & program state.

You want to protect your xml file. You can do this by encrypting. However what do you do with the key?

Because someone can always just reverse engineer (open your dll) en read the key...?

```
public static string Encrypt (string toEncrypt)
{
 byte[] keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes ("12345678901234567890123456789012");
 // 256-AES key
 byte[] toEncryptArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (toEncrypt);
 RijndaelManaged rDel = new RijndaelManaged ();
 rDel.Key = keyArray;
 rDel.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
 // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ciphermode.aspx
 rDel.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
 // better lang support
 ICryptoTransform cTransform = rDel.CreateEncryptor ();
 byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock (toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
 return Convert.ToBase64String (resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
}

public static string Decrypt (string toDecrypt)
{
 byte[] keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes ("12345678901234567890123456789012");
 // AES-256 key
 byte[] toEncryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String (toDecrypt);
 RijndaelManaged rDel = new RijndaelManaged ();
 rDel.Key = keyArray;
 rDel.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
 // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ciphermode.aspx
 rDel.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
 // better lang support
 ICryptoTransform cTransform = rDel.CreateDecryptor ();
 byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock (toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
 return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString (resultArray);
}
```

edit: app is 100% client side.

Comment: Shall we assume this is a client application, and everything should work solely on the client (i.e. without talking to an external server)? If so, then I don't think there's any way to completely protect this: you need to be able to decrypt and encrypt on the same machine, so there's nothing to prevent someone from doing so outside of the normal way of doing it. You can obfuscate it and make it more difficult in any number of ways, sure, but not completely stop it.

Comment: Yes it's a pure client app; no server. Thx

Comment: RijndaelManaged is a symmetric encryption (I believe). Have you considered using public/private (RSA) encryption, encrypt it with the public key and decrypt with the private key?

Comment: No I haven't will check into it now. Edit: How would that help? Where would I keep my private key? => Not on the same machine right? But it has to be all on one machine.

Comment: Both `RijndaelManaged` and `ICryptoTransform` implement/inherit `IDisposable`, so you should be wrapping their usages in `using` statements.

Comment: @TimS. Any obfuscating tips?

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer Please elaborate? I don't see how inheriting IDisposable would help?

Comment: @Thomas this is not in relation to the problem you are asking, sorry. It's a general development issue. Types that implement `IDisposable` (like you're using) should be disposed properly, preferably by `using` blocks. If you'd like me to post an answer with how that would look, I'd be glad to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I have a program (=>game) that saves it state (=>level,..) in an xml file; this state should not be user editable; and I want to prevent people writing patch software that can patch my xml & program state.  You can do this by encrypting. However what do you do with the key? Because someone can always just reverse engineer (open your dll) and read the key.

You have produced a convincing argument that what you want to do is impossible.  Your argument is correct.

Security systems are designed to protect *users* from *attackers*, not to protect *the user's data* from *the users themselves*.

Think about it this way:  the game is a program that can edit the state. The user can run the game. **Therefore the user can run a program that can edit the state**. You don't even need to consider key management because the entire scenario is fundamentally impossible. You can't both *require* that the user be able to run a program that changes the state *and forbid it at the same time*.

If you really want the game state to be protected from the user then the thing that has to give is: **the user must not be allowed to run the game**.  Instead the game must run on *a server which you own*, and the user runs a *client* which communicates with the server. The server is then responsible for determining whether the client is hostile or not, and determining what the game state is.

Since the game is now running on a server that you own, and saving the state to a server which you own, you know that the user is not going to edit the state because *they cannot run a program which does so*.

Comment: This is all 100% true.  While it's certainly the case that it's impossible to prevent the user from doing this, it's at least worth mentioning that you *can* make it harder.  It becomes a case of [walls an latters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/01/17/10257351.aspx), but it's possible (especially for a game) that just making it *hard enough*, even if it's not impossible, is an acceptable business requirement to have (if you are more specific about how hard "hard enough" is).  Game devs (justifiably) spend a lot of time and money working on this clearly insoluble problem.

Comment: +1 for "...the user can run a program that can edit the state" and +1 for @Servy for "...you can make it harder". My bank send to me my balance int html and a e-mail password is in javascript code with a lot of code (+500 chars). I couldn't hack in 2 min and gave up.

Comment: @VitorCanova If your bank is relying on that kind of “security” to protect your money, run away as fast as you can.

Comment: @svick It's just to see the balance. I can't do anything more than see. But I understood your point.

Comment: The problem of walls and ladders prohibits the creation of an industry standard approach, since someone would eventually break it.  This can be mitigated by using an army of developers to constantly update the system.  That being said, some operating systems (e.g., IOS) are defaulted such that most user do **not** have full access to their machines.  Of course, in such a scenario you can could omit encryption entirely; normal users won't have direct access to the settings file at all.

Comment: @Brian It's worth mentioning that even the case you describe is still breakable; the OS is just helping you in making it harder for the user.  Being a client app you can always decompile the code and re-write it to do...whatever, that's just not not as easy as a lot of other options.

Comment: @Servy: Agreed.  But the difference here is that average users won't be willing to make use of the exploit.  In the case of iOS, users who don't want to Jailbreak their device (or otherwise make use of iOS exploits) will not be able to use the hacked app, since the maker of the original application probably won't be able to maintain a listing on the Apple Store (because it's a recompile of someone else's app and thus a violation of Apple's terms).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you ask the user for a key (password). This is built into the OS with APIs like [Data Protection API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx).

If you're looking for a way to hide a secret *from the user* then the problem you're trying to solve is called DRM (Digital Rights Management) and you need a DRM solution.

Comment: In C#, you might want to look at the CngKey class.  Some of the functions there might be useful.

Answer (score -1):

Create a user account service that generates user specific keys. Then the application just needs to encrypt and decrypt the sensitive data you want to protect with it. Each time the game runs make the user log in to his account. The key is never stored in the user's machine so your data is relatively safe (at least almost as safe as your account service).

Downside: You need an internet connection to play the game, but hey, who doesn't have a connection nowdays?

Is this a 100% secure? No, a determined user with enough time could plausibly decrypt his saved game. Of course he would only be able to hack his saved games, so the damage would be minimal (as long as the hacked data is user specific and not shared data).

To make things harder you could always make your service change passwords each few times a given user logs in.

If you want a 100% secure system, or the sensitive data is shared data and not user specific (MMORPG for instance), then, as Eric points out, your only solution would be to have the data in your server, not in the client's machine.

Comment: It's actually a lot easier than decrypting it.  You just need to sniff the network packets sent between this application and the server to see what the encryption key is, or to decompile the code, remove the section of code that does the description/encryption, and then re-compile.

Comment: @Servy: And your point? I see you failed to read that I stated that the security will be as safe as your user account service (or are we going to argue that any user login service is flawed and so easily attacked?). As to recompiling, can you please point out how to sign a hacked exe so that it remains a valid client that can talk to the account service?

Comment: My point is what I opened with; it's a lot easier than you made it seem to break this system, that's all I was saying.  Note that it's *impossible* to secure the network connection from being sniffed by the user; there is no way to secure that communication for the exact same reason that you need it in the first place; such communication would require a key that the user, by definition, needs to have access to.  As for the exe not being signed, the whole point of hacking it would be to prevent it from talking to the service at all; that it can't talk to the service anymore is *the goal*.

Comment: @Servy: so,according to you, any login service is hackable that way? Wow, maybe I should drop all my online accounts then, whatever happened to secured connections through third party certificates...Your point regarding this is mute anyway, as I clearly stated that the system will be as secure as the login service. That said, what would you gain making the application not contact the service if it is unable to decrypt the data files?

Comment: @Servy: It is more difficult to break a system that requires internet connectivity than one that does not (even in InBetween's overly simple approach).  Whether this is enough to justify requiring it is a different question; users would answer no, but plenty of commercial companies have answered yes.  Really, the question this increased difficulty will add more sales (due to making piracy harder) than it loses (due to users *hating* software which requires connectivity).  There may be cases where cost-benefit analysis favors this approach.

Comment: @InBetween: If you make a website that requires login before running a **client-side program**, it's hackable using Servy's approach.  Bank systems run server-side software.

Comment: @InBetween You seem to misunderstand what an encrypted communication prevents against.  When I go into login to google using an encryped connection doesn't prevent *me* from knowing the username and password that I'm sending.  I can see it, Google can see it, and only the two of us can see the response.  You can't see the password that I send.  What you're suggesting is that I wouldn't be able to see the password that I myself am sending.  *That* isn't possible.  In this case, I'm the one running the client, that client is sending the network request.  I can see that request *no matter what*.

Comment: @Brian I'm aware of the fact that, using an internet connection, you're capable of creating protections that are harder to break.  (Note though that the OP *specifically* mentions that he intends to have no internet connection.)  All I was stating, as I said before, is that the OP doesn't need to actually decrypt the encrypted file to "break" the system.  There are easier ways.  Those easier ways may still be hard enough, and that's fine.  It's still important to know the easiest way to break your system, and I was informing the poster and other readers of that method.

Comment: @InBetween The point of preventing the connection entirely would be to stop it from encrypting the information in the first place.  The client itself must have the unencrypted information; it sends it to the service to encrypt it.  You can remove the code that does that, and just have it write out the unencrypted information.  That's what makes the problem so hard.  If the information was only ever unencrypted on the server, and not on the client, then the problem is solvable.

Comment: @Servy: maybe we've lost perspective of the whole issue. The OP was asking about protecting saved plain xml game data and we've ended up pointing out weaknesses that involve modifying the game's source code. Still you are absolutely right about the connection issue, I didn't have my facts straight and the whole issue is that the user is the attacker to begin with.